Mostrar datos en dos datagridview desde dos tablas en DB Browser for SQLite en VB.Net
Quiero mostrar en un formulario FormCerrarCajaDiario con dos datagridview(DGVCerrarCajaDiario y DGVPagoDiario los datos desde las tablas TablaIngresoVentasProductos y TablaPagosDiarios (el primer datagrid desde la primera tabla y el segundo datagrid desde la otra tabla), el DGVCerrarCajaDiario con 8 columnas y la TablaIngresoVentasProductos con 19 columnas, el DGVPagoDiario con 5 columnas y la TablaPagosDiarios con 5 columnas, datagrid y tablas coinciden en los nombres de columnas, el DGVCerrarCajaDiario no me carga los datos y el DGVPagoDiario si carga los datos, con dos procedimientos para cargar desde el evento Load del FormCerrarCajaDiario(MostrarCerrarCajaDiaria() y MostrarCerrarPagoDiario()), en el primer procedimiento si coloco Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.Rows.Clear() mensaje de error:
SystemArgumentException: 'No se puede borrar esta lista.', 

Si elimino o comento esta línea y ejecuto el procedimiento completo, mensaje de error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se pueden agregar filas mediante programación a la colección de filas de DataGridView cuando el control está enlazado a datos.' 

Y el DGVCerarCajaDiario no muestra ningún dato en fila ni columnas; paso la composición de la tabla
TablaIngresoVentasProductos`CREATE TABLE TablaIngresoVentasProductos
(
CODE TEXT(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
CATEGORY TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
PRODUCTS TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
IMPORT DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
CANTID DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
SUBVALUE DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
DATEFECHA DATE NOT NULL,
VALOR_COSTE DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
COSTE DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
VALOR_IVA DECIMAL(10, 2),
IVA DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
DEDUCTION DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
TOTAL DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
CONDITION TEXT(50),
FORMA_PAGO TEXT(50),
NOMB_TARJETA TEXT(50),
NUM_TARJETA INT,
ORIG_CHEQUE TEXT(50),
NUM_CHEQUE INT 
);`composición de la otra tabla `CREATE TABLE TablaPagosDiarios
(
DESTINO TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
DETALLE TEXT(100) NOT NULL,
FORMAPAGO TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
IMPORTETOTAL DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
FECHAACTUAL DATE
);

procedimiento para mostrar MostrarCerrarCajaDiaria()
Private Sub MostrarCerrarCajaDiaria()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, FORMA_PAGO As String
    Dim IMPORT, CANTID, SUBVALUE As Decimal
    Dim DATEFECHA As Date
    'Dim DGVCerrarCajaDiario As New DataGridView

    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        sql = "SELECT CODE,CATEGORY,PRODUCTS,IMPORT,CANTID,SUBVALUE,DATEFECHA,FORMA_PAGO FROM TablaIngresoVentasProductos"
        Dim adaptador As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        Dim DSet As New DataSet()
        adaptador.Fill(DSet, "TablaIngresoVentasProductos")

        'Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.Rows.Clear()

        ' Crear una lista para almacenar los valores de IMPORTETOTAL
        Dim importSubvList As New List(Of Decimal)

        If DSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            For i = 0 To DSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                CODE = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("CODE")
                CATEGORY = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("CATEGORY")
                PRODUCTS = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("PRODUCTS")
                IMPORT = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("IMPORT")
                CANTID = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("CANTID")
                SUBVALUE = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("SUBVALUE")
                DATEFECHA = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("DATEFECHA")
                FORMA_PAGO = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("FORMA_PAGO")

                ' Verificar si el valor ya existe en la lista
                If Not importSubvList.Contains(SUBVALUE) Then
                    ' Agregar el valor a la lista
                    importSubvList.Add(SUBVALUE)

                    Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.Rows.Add(CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, IMPORT, CANTID, SUBVALUE.ToString("N2"), DATEFECHA, FORMA_PAGO)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    Call sumarCantVent()
    Call sumarSubtotalVent()
    Call sumarImporteTotal()
    Call resultadoVentasPagos()

End Sub` procedimiento para mostrar MostrarCerrarPagoDiario() `Private Sub MostrarCerrarPagoDiario()
    Dim consulta As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO As String
    Dim IMPORTETOTAL As Decimal
    Dim FECHAACTUAL As Date
    Dim DGVPagoDiario As New DataGridView

    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        consulta = "SELECT DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO, IMPORTETOTAL, FECHAACTUAL FROM TablaPagosDiarios"
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(consulta, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)

        ' Limpiar las filas existentes en el DataGridView
        Me.DGVPagoDiario.Rows.Clear()

        ' Crear una lista para almacenar los valores de IMPORTETOTAL
        Dim importeTotalList As New List(Of Decimal)

        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                DESTINO = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("DESTINO")
                DETALLE = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("DETALLE")
                FORMAPAGO = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("FORMAPAGO")
                IMPORTETOTAL = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Field(Of Decimal)("IMPORTETOTAL")
                FECHAACTUAL = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("FECHAACTUAL")

                ' Verificar si el valor ya existe en la lista
                If Not importeTotalList.Contains(IMPORTETOTAL) Then
                    ' Agregar el valor a la lista
                    importeTotalList.Add(IMPORTETOTAL)

                    ' Agregar la fila al DataGridView
                    Me.DGVPagoDiario.Rows.Add(DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO, IMPORTETOTAL.ToString("N2"), FECHAACTUAL)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

    Call sumarSubtotalPago()
    Call sumarImporteTotal()
    Call resultadoVentasPagos()

End Sub

los procedimientos son casi similares y no encuentro el motivo de la no carga en el primer datagrid, intenté con DataSet, con DataBinding, colocando dos botones para cargar
Private Sub btnMostrarVentaDiaria_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMostrarVentaDiaria.Click
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If

    ' Crear el DataTable manualmente
    Dim DT As New DataTable()
    DT.Columns.Add("CODE")
    DT.Columns.Add("CATEGORY")
    DT.Columns.Add("PRODUCTS")
    DT.Columns.Add("IMPORT")
    DT.Columns.Add("CANTID")
    DT.Columns.Add("SUBVALUE")
    DT.Columns.Add("DATEFECHA")
    DT.Columns.Add("FORMA_PAGO")

    ' Consulta SQL sin espacios vacíos entre columnas
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, IMPORT, CANTID, SUBVALUE, DATEFECHA, FORMA_PAGO FROM TablaIngresoVentasProductos"
    Using DA As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        DA.Fill(DT)
    End Using

    ' Asignar el DataTable al DataSource del DataGridView
    Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.DataSource = DT
End Sub

Private Sub btnMostrarPagoDiario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMostrarPagoDiario.Click
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If

    ' Crear el DataTable manualmente
    Dim DT As New DataTable()
    DT.Columns.Add("DESTINO")
    DT.Columns.Add("DETALLE")
    DT.Columns.Add("FORMA_PAGO")
    DT.Columns.Add("IMPORTETOTAL")
    DT.Columns.Add("FECHAACTUAL")

    ' Consulta SQL para la tabla de pagos diarios
    Dim consulta As String = "SELECT DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO, IMPORTETOTAL, FECHAACTUAL FROM TablaPagosDiarios"
    Using adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(consulta, conn)
        adapter.Fill(DT)
    End Using

    ' Asignar el DataTable al DataSource del DataGridView
    Me.DGVPagoDiario.DataSource = DT
End Sub

Tampoco me dió resultado en el DGVCerrarCajaDiario, en el DGVPagosDiarios me carga normal, hago la aclaración en primer datagrid que nombro SELECT 8 de las 19 columnas y en el segundo datagridview SELECT 5 de las 5 columnas, revisé en el cuadro de Propiedades y los valores similares en ambos DataGridView, consulté con la IA en Google y Edge, me dieron varias sugerencias y alternativas de código y ninguna dio resultado, si alguno de los frecuentes asistidores de esta Plataforma genial que pueda darme una mano, agradecido.

No entiendo el lio que hiciste... porque cargas las grillas de dos formas distitnas??? o usas el datasource, o le cargas las filas a mano... las dos cosas no... de ahi es el lio que tenes con todo...

gbianchi<>, Agradezco tu respuesta, lo que estás viendo, son dos formas diferentes implementadas para cargar, los datagridview, a pesar de usar el mismo formato en los 2 procedimientos, ejecutando paso a paso por instrucciones, me recorre todas las filas mostrándome los valores, incluída la línea:  Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.Rows.Add(CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, IMPORT, CANTID, SUBVALUE, DATEFECHA, FORMA_PAGO), pero en el mensaje del Catch:  System.InvalidOperationException: No se pueden agregar filas mediante programación a la colección de filas de DataGridView cuando el control está enlazado datos

Es que si esta enlazado no podes agregar filas a mano.. el error te esta diciendo el problema...

gbianchi<>, Solucionado el problema, a la línea indicada le antepuse  Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.DataSource = Nothing, lo hice en los dos datagridview, cargan los datos perfecto. Gracias por la deferencia de contestar..

OK.... lo resolviste.. pero no tiene ningun sentido... o sea.. o usas el datasource y trabajas sobre la lista enlazada.. o no lo usas.. eso que hiciste, fue basciamente decir, lo uso, pero despues no lo uso... no es algo con mucho sentido.. se entiende??? si no lo ibas a usar, para que lo usaste en un principio???

gbianchi<> Con este mismo formato para los dos datagrdview resolví el problema  Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.DataSource = Nothing
Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.Rows.Add(CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, IMPORT, CANTID, SUBVALUE, DATEFECHA, FORMA_PAGO)
            Me.DGVPagoDiario.DataSource = Nothing
            Me.DGVPagoDiario.Rows.Add(DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO, IMPORTETOTAL, FECHAACTUAL)


De esta forma resolví el problema, anteponiendo el DataSource = Nothing, los dos datagrid con el mismo formato de carga:
Private Sub MostrarCerrarCajaDiaria()
    Dim sql, CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, IMPORT, CANTID, SUBVALUE, DATEFECHA, FORMA_PAGO As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        sql = "SELECT CODE,CATEGORY,PRODUCTS,IMPORT,CANTID,SUBVALUE,DATEFECHA,FORMA_PAGO FROM TablaIngresoVentasProductos"
        Dim adaptador As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        Dim DSet As New DataSet()
        adaptador.Fill(DSet)

        If DSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No hay datos existentes")
        Else
            'Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.Rows.Clear()
            For j = 0 To DSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                CODE = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("CODE")
                CATEGORY = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("CATEGORY")
                PRODUCTS = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("PRODUCTS")
                IMPORT = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("IMPORT")
                CANTID = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("CANTID")
                SUBVALUE = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("SUBVALUE")
                DATEFECHA = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("DATEFECHA")
                FORMA_PAGO = DSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("FORMA_PAGO")

                Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.DataSource = Nothing
                Me.DGVCerrarCajaDiario.Rows.Add(CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, IMPORT, CANTID, SUBVALUE, DATEFECHA, FORMA_PAGO)

            Next
        End If
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    sumarCantVent()
    sumarSubtotalVent()
    'Call resultadoVentasPagos()
End Sub;

Este es el primer datagridview del formulario, y aquí el segundo datagridview del mismo formulario:
Private Sub MostrarCerrarPagoDiario()
    Dim consulta As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO, IMPORTETOTAL, FECHAACTUAL As String

    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        consulta = "SELECT DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO, IMPORTETOTAL, FECHAACTUAL FROM TablaPagosDiarios"
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(consulta, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        'Me.DGVPagoDiario.Rows.Clear()
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No hay datos existentes")
        Else
            Me.DGVPagoDiario.Rows.Clear()
            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                DESTINO = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("DESTINO")
                DETALLE = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("DETALLE")
                FORMAPAGO = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("FORMAPAGO")
                IMPORTETOTAL = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("IMPORTETOTAL")
                FECHAACTUAL = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("FECHAACTUAL")

                Me.DGVPagoDiario.DataSource = Nothing
                Me.DGVPagoDiario.Rows.Add(DESTINO, DETALLE, FORMAPAGO, IMPORTETOTAL, FECHAACTUAL)
            Next
        End If

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

    sumarImporteVent()
    'Call resultadoVentasPagos()

End Sub

